# What does * do to a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to understand what * is doing to data to only print the letters in the list.

```
data = ["f", "o", "u", "r"]
print(*data, sep=' ')
```

Comment: It "unpacks" the array, much like the spread operator in recent versions of JavaScript

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right syntax? I get a compile error from this code...

Comment: @Jamin : try on Python 3, it will work

Comment: Oh i see thanks Harsha